# is there any standard warning (stdwarn) like stdout and stderr?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, console, stdout

Is there any standard warning (`stdwarn`) like `stdout` and `stderr`?

Actually in my **node.js** application everything that I'm consoling using `console.error()` is adding to file `log_err.log`

and everything else like `console.warn(), console.info() and console.log()` is adding to `log_std.log` file, but i want warning messages in different log file.

something similar to:

```
node server.js > log_std.log 2> log_err.log 3> log_warn.log
```

Here `>` is used for standard log, `2>` us used for standard error to print in file and

`3>` is nothing here but I want to know is there similar syntex to print warning messages in **log_warn.log** file.

Comment: Do you mean warnings emitted by `process.emitWarning()` or e.g unhandled promise rejection warning?

Comment: actually in my node application i'm using console to print _log,error and warnings_.

like:
`console.log('simple log');
console.warn('warning');
console.error('error');`

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no `stdwarn`. But you should do it by yourself. It will give you more control over your logs. Create your own logger with `log` `warn` and `error` methods and decide what you want to do with it.

```
var Log = {
    log: function(msg) {
        // output message to your log
        // it can be file, or syslog drain etc.
    },
    warn: function(msg) {
        //...
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        //...
    }
};
```

Additionally, you can catch `uncaughtException` and `unhandledRejection` events and also send them to your log:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => { Log.error(err.stack); process.exit(1)});
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => Log.warn(reason.stack || reason));
```